# choosing smallest match for each set of matches between 2 tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I am trying to query based on the relationship between a column from each table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, value INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE bar (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, value INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));

describe foo;
```

> ```
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | value | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> ```

```
describe bar;
```

> ```
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | value | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> +-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> ```

In this simple example, assume the tables are filled as follows

```
INSERT INTO foo (value) VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
INSERT INTO bar (value) VALUES(5), (8), (9), (2), (10);

select * from foo;
```

> ```
> +----+-------+
> | id | value |
> +----+-------+
> |  1 |     1 |
> |  2 |     2 |
> |  3 |     3 |
> |  4 |     4 |
> |  5 |     5 |
> |  6 |     6 |
> |  7 |     7 |
> |  8 |     8 |
> |  9 |     9 |
> | 10 |    10 |
> +----+-------+
> ```

```
select * from bar;
```

> ```
> +----+-------+
> | id | value |
> +----+-------+
> |  1 |     5 |
> |  2 |     8 |
> |  3 |     9 |
> |  4 |     2 |
> |  5 |    10 |
> +----+-------+
> ```

Now, for each row in foo, I would like to get the id of the column in bar where the value of bar is the smallest value greater than the value of foo.  That is I would like to retrieve a table like

> ```
> +--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
> | foo.id | bar.id | foo.value | bar.value |
> +--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
> |    1   |    4   |     1     |     2     |
> |    2   |    1   |     2     |     5     |
> |    3   |    1   |     3     |     5     |
> |    4   |    1   |     4     |     5     |
> |    5   |    2   |     5     |     8     |
> |    6   |    2   |     6     |     8     |
> |    7   |    2   |     7     |     8     |
> |    8   |    3   |     8     |     9     |
> |    9   |    5   |     9     |    10     |
> +--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
> ```

Note that foo row 10 has no corresponding row in bar that is greater than its value so it doesn't get selected.  I know how to find all of the pairs where the value in bar is greater than the value in foo:

```
SELECT foo.id as foo_id, bar.id as bar_id from foo, bar where foo.value < bar.value;
```

but I cannot figure out how to find the smallest value of bar in each grouping of the foo ids.  Most of the other questions along these lines that I've seen have assumed you are trying to do this from one table, not multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do it for you:

```
SELECT foo.id as `foo.id`, bar.id AS `bar.id`, foo.value AS `foo.value`, bar.value AS `bar.value`
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON bar.value = (
  SELECT MIN(bar.value) FROM bar WHERE foo.value < bar.value
)
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1a0c3/16) is a link to the sqlfiddle where you can see it in action.

Comment: This is perfect and so much simpler than everything I had tried!

Comment: Glad it helped!